# How to go 2 rows down instead of 1 through loop/counter- VBA

Tags: excel, vba, loops, counter, rows

I have the vba below that allows me to go down 1 row every loop. But I want it to go down 2 rows instead of just 1. How would I go about doing this?

```
Sub Languages()

 Range("L2").Select
    ActiveCell.Range("K1:L1").Select


    For counter = 2 To 6
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
        ActiveChart.ApplyChartTemplate ( _
            "C:\Users\arboari\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Charts\1Language.crtx")
        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Master Sheet'!$B$" & counter & ":$F$" & counter)
        ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Charts"
        With ActiveChart
            .HasTitle = False
            .Axes(xlCategory).Select
            .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='Master Sheet'!$B$:$B$3"
            .Parent.Top = 50
            .Parent.Left = c * 130
        End With
        Sheets("Master Sheet").Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1:I1").Select

        c = c + 3
    Next counter

End Sub
```

Thanks!

Comment: (I think you have a typo here: `FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='Master Sheet'!$B$:$B$3"`  Did you forget to add the first cell's row here on SO, or also in your code?)

Comment: If you had simply googled your question, you will have come across countless examples of how to do this on the very first page of results.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub Languages()

 Range("L2").Select
    ActiveCell.Range("K1:L1").Select


    For counter = 2 To 6 step 2 'loop every two rows
        ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select
        ActiveChart.ApplyChartTemplate ( _
            "C:\Users\arboari\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Templates\Charts\1Language.crtx")
        ActiveChart.SetSourceData Source:=Range("'Master Sheet'!$B$" & counter & ":$F$" & counter)
        ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsObject, Name:="Charts"
        With ActiveChart
            .HasTitle = False
            .Axes(xlCategory).Select
            .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='Master Sheet'!$B$:$B$3"
            .Parent.Top = 50
            .Parent.Left = c * 130
        End With
        Sheets("Master Sheet").Select
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Range("A1:I1").Select

        c = c + 3
    Next counter

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add `Step 2` after `For counter = 2 To 6` --> `For counter = 2 To 6 Step 2`.

This will use `2`, then next loop step two up, so `4`, then again to `6`.

<sub>More info on [`Step` here](http://www.ozgrid.com/VBA/for-loop-step.htm)</sub>